# Cannot load modules/libphp7.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/libphp7.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm using linux (ubuntu) ec2 instance
and I've installed php 7 and httpd but when I run the following command

```
service httpd start
```

I get the following error

```
  Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 353 of 
 /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 6 of 
 /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp7.so into server: 
 /etc/httpd/modules/libphp7.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config
```

any one can help

Comment: try to add `sudo <commands>`

Comment: I did but it doesn't work

Comment: what's that of output error?

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri same error